# Why Java prohibits array initializer as a method invocation argument?

Tags: java, jls

In Java we can define an array variable and initialize it like this:

```java
int[] prime10 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
```

In JLS, the right side of assignment is called [`ArrayCreationExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1). The initializer in JLS syntax terms is [`ArrayInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).

As all expressions, `ArrayCreationExpression` can be used in a method call arguments list:

```java
callMe(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 });
```

However, we can also use shorter form of [`VariableInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), with `ArrayInitializer` only:

```java
int[] prime10 = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
```

but we can't use the same initializer in a [method call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

```java
// ILLEGAL IN JAVA
callMe({ 2, 3, 5, 7 });
```

Of course it is understandable why compilation fails, when analyzing the syntax — an excerpt from JLS:

```
VariableDeclarator:
  VariableDeclaratorId [= VariableInitializer]

VariableInitializer:
  Expression 
  ArrayInitializer

MethodInvocation:
  MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
  // plus other variants...

ArgumentList:
  Expression {, Expression}
```

but why such a decision was made? Why not make `ArrayInitializer` an `Expression`, or at least add a variant with `ArrayInitializer` to `ArgumentList`? Is it plainly syntactical, or there are other causes (type inference, maybe) which prohibit such an extension?

**UPDATE**

After some comments in the spirit "how would you know the type of `{1, 2, 3}`", a technical clarification.

In method invocation, it is method formal parameters that decide the allowed types of arguments. So if I have a method declaration:

```java
void callMe(Number[] numbers) {
  //...
}
```

then the questioned call

```java
callMe({ 1, 2, 3 }); // still ILLEGAL in Java
```

would mean

```java
callMe(new Number[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

So no problem here. My question is not for opinionated "who needs this" — who needed lambdas, diamonds and `var` anyway ;) — but rather, what prohibits (formally) such a construct from JLS point of view, or at least from the point of view of "Java architects" introducing such features into the language?

Answer (score 2):

What would be the array type of `{2, 3, 5, 7}` ?

byte[] ???  short[] ???  char[] ???  long[] ???

If it's stated explicitly it's right there.  If it's inferred using whatever rule is decided for it, that's yet one more rule to learn for the developer.

(PS in variable initializers it can be inferred from the type declaration of the variable.  In method invocations it cannot be inferred from the method signature, because method binding works exactly the other way round : the argument types have to be known first because they are a determinant factor in determining which method is concerned.)

Comment: "that's yet one more rule to learn for the developer" This argument is pretty weak when you think about the additional inference rules that were added to Java like the diamond operator or `val` since Java 10. So "new rules" aren't an issue for the Java Maintainers.

Comment: Not that much into java anymore these days, but I do think ***lots*** of people have already been bitten by the flip side of the "comfort" of val.

Comment: If or if not people had issues with a new rule doesn't actually matter now, what matters is if the Java architect chose to not implement a new feature because it meant new rules. The addition of other stuff (like diamond operator or `val`) shows that new rules doesn't seem to matter that much. So that alone wouldn't be the reason why it hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is understandable, why such a decision was made. What set of rules would you propose to infer the type of {1, 2, 3} or {1, "dasqwe", 'c'}, etc? Creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: You don't need any special rules, they are already there, called [invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3); when calling a method, it is the method declaration formal parameters which tell the compiler what types to expect. So the array's component type would be decided by the method declaration. As for `{1, "dasqwe", 'c' }`, it is not a problem as long as you know the component type (as suggested above, from formal parameters), ex. `Number[] b = { 1, 1.2, new BigDecimal("1.20000000001")` works perfectly fine.